# How does boost log determine the file permissions it should create log files with?

Tags: logging, boost, permissions

I am having difficulties determining the way how the boost log library determines and assigns file permissions to log files it creates.

I have an application that for the longest of times created log files with file permissions set to 644 for the log files using the boost log library.

However, recently, the log files are created with the file permissions set to 600. This is posing some issues with log access, as the user the application is started with is a custom user for that specific application in order to manage file access on the platform. If I need to access the application log, I log in onto the platform with a user that is part of the same group as the user for the application, so with 644 this is not an issue. However, with the file permissions set to 600, I am having to elevate my rights to root just to access the log files.

Comment: I think you might be having a restrictive `umask`.

Comment: That does seem to be the issue, as on the system I have issues with umask is set to 0077, while on an older system that does not have the issue it is set to 0002. I'll have to test to see if that fixes my issue.